# asp.web api load balancing system

Tags: asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

I want to build a asp.net web api server that can re-route incoming HTTP request to other web api servers. Main server will be master and its only job will be accepting and routing to other servers. Slave servers will inform master server when they started and ready to accept http requests. Slave servers must not only inform they alive but they should send which api they support. I think I have to re-map routing tables in master server in runtime. Is it possible?
 This seems like load balancing according to functionality . Is there any way to do this ?  I have to write a load balancer for web api any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in the application layer?  What if you are re-directing TLS traffic?  Do you want to terminate everything at the load balancer?

Comment: This is a school project so security is not too much important.

Comment: @AhmetArslan I have the same task, could you share your solution idea with us?

Comment: @Tomas , sen me your mail adress, I will share my solution. Its long story, you can inspect code.